# How we can create dynamic layout of columns with the help of bootstrap?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a dynamic column layout with the help of twitter bootstrap. All yellow blocks are generated in a for loop

Example

```
<div class="container">

<div class="col-lg-4">
Sidebar
</div>
<div class="col-lg-8">
<div class="col-lg-4"></div>
<div class="col-lg-4"></div>
<div class="col-lg-4"></div>
<div class="col-lg-4"></div>
<div class="col-lg-4"></div>
<div class="col-lg-4"></div>
<div class="col-lg-4"></div>
<div class="col-lg-4"></div>
<div class="col-lg-4"></div>
<div class="col-lg-4"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try use col-sm col-xs or col-md. You using de class to desktop resolution. You should use these other three class to make a responsive layout. Read this page: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Comment: yes i tried.But it does not help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the row elements:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        Sidebar
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">2</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">4</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">5</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">6</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">7</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">8</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">9</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Take a look [at this demo bootply](http://www.bootply.com/sZ75AF4pbW)

Comment: thanks for reply..But I want to auto adjust this layout.Because I have not fixed number of square box.

Comment: @Ashish then take a look [at this bootply instead](http://www.bootply.com/37m4L318w2)